# How to quickly get the array of multiplicities

Tags: arrays, matlab, unique, accumarray

What is the fastest way of taking an array `A` and outputing both `unique(A)` [i.e. the set of unique array elements of `A`] as well as the multiplicity array which takes in its i-th place the i-th multiplicity of the i-th entry of `unique(A)` in `A`.

That's a mouthful, so here's an example. Given `A=[1 1 3 1 4 5 3]`, I want:

1. `unique(A)=[1 3 4 5]`
2. `mult = [3 2 1 1]`

This can be done with a tedious for loop, but would like to know if there is a way to exploit the array nature of MATLAB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
uA = unique(A);
mult = histc(A,uA);
```

Alternatively:

```
uA = unique(A);
mult = sum(bsxfun(@eq, uA(:).', A(:)));
```

---

**Benchmarking**

```
N = 100;
A = randi(N,1,2*N); %// size 1 x 2*N

%// Luis Mendo, first approach
tic
for iter = 1:1e3;
    uA = unique(A);
    mult = histc(A,uA);
end
toc

%// Luis Mendo, second approach    
tic
for iter = 1:1e3;
    uA = unique(A);
    mult = sum(bsxfun(@eq, uA(:).', A(:)));
end
toc

%'// chappjc
tic
for iter = 1:1e3;
    [uA,~,ic] = unique(A);    % uA(ic) == A
    mult= accumarray(ic.',1);
end
toc
```

Results with `N = 100`:

```
Elapsed time is 0.096206 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.235686 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.154150 seconds.
```

Results with `N = 1000`:

```
Elapsed time is 0.481456 seconds.
Elapsed time is 4.534572 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.550606 seconds.
```

Comment: Do you have any opinion as to which of those two is faster?

Comment: @GregorianFunk I don't know... Also, it may depend on the size of `A`. Sometimes one solution is fastest for small sizes but not for large. Do give them a try!

Comment: @GregorianFunk I've done some testing (see edited answer). The first is clearly faster. The answer by chappjc is very close

Answer (score 2):

```
[uA,~,ic] = unique(A);    % uA(ic) == A
mult = accumarray(ic.',1);
```

[`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) is *very* fast. Unfortunately, `unique` gets slow with 3 outputs.

---

Late addition:

```
uA = unique(A);
mult = nonzeros(accumarray(A(:),1,[],@sum,0,true))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
S = sparse(A,1,1);
[uA,~,mult] = find(S);
```

I've found this elegant solution in [an old Newsgroup thread](http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/68132).

Testing with the [benchmark of Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21710841/1606707) for `N = 1000` :

```
Elapsed time is 0.228704 seconds. % histc
Elapsed time is 1.838388 seconds. % bsxfun
Elapsed time is 0.128791 seconds. % sparse
```

(On my machine, `accumarray` results in `Error: Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.`)